# Teamcity doesn't create label when built from branch

Tags: svn, teamcity, labeling

I'm trying to create flexible Teamcity build configuration for my project.

First, I create svn VCS root from:

> svn://mycompany.com/myproject

This repository contains of these folders:

- /trunk
- /versions/1.1
- /tags/...

Then, I configure checkout rules as:

> +: %checkoutRule% => .

This means that agent will checkout sources from parameter, defined by user who triggers build. %checkoutRules% can has value of "trunk" to build from trunk or "versions/1.1" to build from version 1.1 branch.

At last, I configure labeling as %checkoutRule% => tags, which means, that every build should create tag.

So, my problem is that when I trigger build for "trunk", tag is created, but when I trigger build from version/1.1, tag is not created. Build from version/1.1 has additional label:

> Branch:   versions/2.1:: versions/2.1

Need help, how can I avoid these problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple issue. Update to version 8.1.

Important updates for me:
* you can now configure branches to label. Default is

> +:<default>

I just changed to

> +:*

And now any branch build creates a label.

Comment: I think my problem is similar to yours, but I couldn't understand how the answer applies in my use case. What does +:* do? If you have a minute, could you look at my question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221691/how-do-i-set-up-a-teamcity-vcs-label-svn-when-using-a-checkout-rule