# How do I set up a TeamCity VCS label (SVN) when using a checkout rule?

Tags: svn, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

How do I label my SVN project with TeamCity VCS labeling if I am using a checkout rule?

I read the checkout rule docs, but I'm having a hard time understanding the relationship between VCS labeling and checkout rules in TeamCity.

My SVN structure looks like:

```
https://my.internalsvn.com/(...)/myproject/branches/gattaca-dev
https://my.internalsvn.com/(...)/myproject/tags
https://my.internalsvn.com/(...)/myproject/trunk
```

In TeamCity, my VCS root is configured to:

```
https://my.internalsvn.com/(...)/myproject
```

When I run the build, I want it to be executed in the current working directory, so I set up a Checkout Rule that looks like:

```
+:branches/gattaca-dev => .
```

When I add the VCS Labeling build feature, it tells me:

> Failed: Failed to set label 'build-6': No labeling rules found for
>   checkout rules branches/gattaca-dev=>

What do I have to set so that the branch I am building (which is configured to "." from the checkout rule) gets tagged?

```
https://my.internalsvn.com/(...)/myproject/tags/build-6
```

How do I set the labeling rule for a checkout rule? Does it go in the checkout rule itself? Or do I need to edit the VCS root and make a copy for this specific build?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work by using a **%vcsBranch%** parameter.

The labeling setting on my VCS root becomes:

```
%vcsBranch%=>tags
```

...and my Checkout Rule becomes:

```
+:%vcsBranch% => .
```

I'm not sure whether this is the best solution. I would've liked to be able to set up custom labeling rules just for this Checkout Rule, rather than hard-coding it in the VCS root. I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Additional feedback is welcome.